# Flutter Map is not changing the map image

Tags: flutter

I am using the *flutter_map* and when updating the latitude and longitude of the map, Marker changes however the map image does not change.

What would be missing for the image to follow the new latitude and longitude?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Map',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Map Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 
  double lat;
  double long;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    lat = 25.7751;
    long = -80.2105;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget> [
          new FlutterMap(
            options: new MapOptions(
              minZoom: 10.0,
              center:  new LatLng(
                lat,
                long,
              )
            ),
            layers: [
              new TileLayerOptions(
                urlTemplate: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                subdomains: ['a','b','c']
              ),
              new MarkerLayerOptions(
                markers: [
                  new Marker(
                    width: 45.0,
                    height: 45.0,
                    point: new LatLng(
                      lat,
                      long,
                    ),
                    builder: (context)=> new Container(
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.add_location),
                        onPressed: () {
                          print('Marker tapped!');
                        }
                      )
                    )
                  )
                ]
              )
            ]
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            lat = 34.0898373;
            long = -118.5010028;
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it was necessary to use `MapController` to insert new markers and change the center.

Follow the code working:

```
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/plugin_api.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Map',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Map Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  MapController mapController;

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 
  static LatLng london = LatLng(51.5, -0.09);
  static LatLng los_angeles = LatLng(34.0522342, -118.2436849);

  MapController mapController;

  var _markers = <Marker>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    mapController = MapController();
    _markers.add(createMarker(london));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  Marker createMarker(LatLng latLng) {
    return Marker(
      width: 80.0,
      height: 80.0,
      point: latLng,
      builder: (ctx) => Container(
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.add_location),
          onPressed: () {
            
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget> [
          new FlutterMap(
            mapController: mapController,
            options: new MapOptions(
              minZoom: 0.0,
              center:  london,
            ),
            layers: [
              new TileLayerOptions(
                urlTemplate: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                subdomains: ['a','b','c']
              ),
              new MarkerLayerOptions(markers: _markers)
            ]
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _markers.clear();
            _markers.add(createMarker(los_angeles));
            mapController.move(los_angeles, 9.0);
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue for this in the flutter_map's repository: https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map/issues/10

Make sure to include the latest version of the package.
However, if that doesn't work, there are some possible solutions in the comments of the issue.